# Remove Alt-F2 history - Trying to remove password.

Tags: unity

How do I remove the history for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?

I accidentally typed my password in there and now I cannot get rid of it.

I have tried the old way for Gnome2 which was under gnome-settings. I have also tried unity-runner and set that to default. Neither of them work.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and Gnome 3. I have tried every method that I was able to find on the internet thus far and nothing has worked. My <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> history remains. Even tried a complete removal of Gnome and re-install no luck.

If anybody could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove everything from the history just run

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell command-history
```

If you only want to remove some parts of the history, than it is easiest to just start `dconf-editor` and remove the unwanted command from the history under org->gnome->shell-> command-history.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't use gnome ATM, but minor research came up with this for gnome3:

```
 Install dconf-tools.

 Run dconf Editor and navigate to /desktop/unity/runner/history
```

(from http://www.techques.com/question/24-122473/Delete-Alt-F2-history)

Comment: Since this appears to be a valid answer I'll let the proper contents remain. Further hate messages won't be tolerated.