# Gnome Shell command prompt history

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell, bash-history

I have a question regarding the Gnome Shell command prompt (Alt+F2).

I already know that I can [delete/reset the command history using dconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402861/remove-alt-f2-history-trying-to-remove-password), but is there a way to completely disable it?

Also, where is the history saved to? My .bash_history is write-protected as a work-around, which means I can still have the handful of commands I want in it. It’d be great if I could do something similar for the Gnome Shell command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around a bit, I found it in `~/.config/dconf/user`.

That's not a text file, however, it's a [GVDB file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf). You can edit it with the "dconf Editor" application: descend to org.gnome.shell, and you can edit the "command-history" key.

Or, from the command line:

```
# query
gsettings get org.gnome.shell command-history
# clear history
gsettings set org.gnome.shell command-history '[]'
```

Comment: Yeah, but you'll have to do this every single time (it gets reset once you start running commands again). I believe OP is aware of this, from the question: "*I already know that I can delete/reset the command history using dconf, but is there a way to completely disable it?*"

Comment: Ah yes. Downvote me if you like. I'll leave this answer here as it may be helpful to other readers.

Comment: Maybe post it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/402861/remove-alt-f2-history-trying-to-remove-password

Comment: As I found out by my usual method of trial and error, you can also use this to set the commands you desire, _if_ you use the correct quotes (I’ll probably never understand the logic behind that, though):  
`gsettings set org.gnome.shell command-history '["firefox"]'`  
So I just put that in a small quick-and-dirty script that resets the command prompt every X minutes. That’s good enough for my purposes.  
@glenn-jackman, @pomsky  
Thanks everybody for your imput.